# How to assign ships to a specific Firecloud warp-chunnel?

Tags: vga-planets

I'm playing the game [VGA Planets](http://planets.nu) and I have chosen the Cyborg as race.

Currently I have two different **Fireclouds** on the same Planet, my whole army plus two freighters with heavily needed resources for my starbase.

I want that my army jump with one **Firecloud** to a nearby planet and the freighters should jump with the other **Firecloud** to my starbase. How can I assign ships to their dedicated **Firecloud**?

Maybe the same friendly codes will work?

Comment: I still play this occasionally on DOSBox.  I'm glad to see others do too.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately no. The first Firecloud to jump (i.e. the one with the lowest ID) will take all your ships in the same location along with it.

But it will work for your allies, if they have ships at the same location. Ships that do not belong to you will be carried through the chunnel only under certain conditions (matching the friendly code, being cloaked or at warp 0.)